# Abstract class has operator chaining operation. Subclass implement operator chaining

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am making an interface for std::stringstream and I'd like to implement the << operator.

I am thinking of doing something like this:

"IStringStream.h"

```
class IStringStream {

public:

virtual IStringStream& operator << (const IStringStream &rhs) = 0;

}

virtual ~IStringStream(){}
```

MyStringStream.h

```
class MyStringStream:IStringStream {
private:
    std::stringstream ss;
public:
    virtual IStringStream& operator << (const IStringStream &rhs) override;
}
```

MyStringStream.cpp

```
MyStringStream::MyStringStream() {
     ss.str("");
}

MyStringStream::MyStringStream(Generic Type(?)T) {
     ss << T;
}

IStringStream & IStringStream::operator << (const IStringStream &rhs) {
     ss << rhs.ss; // Something like this?
}
```

Is this the way to do it?

Comment: (A) C++ doesn't need interfaces, (B) interfaces are only useful for dynamic dispatch, which I doubt you need, (C) That specific interface, that streams out other streams, doesn't appear useful.

Comment: Please explain how you wish to you use your class.

Comment: operator<< should be a free function.

Comment: I want to export it in a DLL and warnings tell me to create an dll-interface for it.

Comment: @terminix00 we're probably not talking about the same kind of "interface" here. I suspect you're after `__declspec(dllexport)` or something related. If this is the case, I suggest you post *that* question instead, because this one won't solve your problem at all.

Comment: Hi, Why doesn't the dll like it when I use std::stringstream? Once I include it, the program breaks and gives me a debug assertion error is_block_valid. Why?